# Central limit theorem (CLT), average over 80 students but sum up over 52 weeks

Tags: self-study, central-limit-theorem

[image]
Because we took the average over 80 students but sum up over 52 weeks, I feel that it’s correct only under certain assumptions but I can’t pinpoint them. Are they the following?

1. The distribution in each week (over the different students) is the identical.
2. The distribution for each student (over the different weeks) is the identical.

Comment: The CLT doesn't apply here as the observations per individual are not independent.  It may not apply even if there were independent as N may not be large enough.

Comment: Please edit the duplicate rather than re-posting variants of it.

Comment: Hi, @whuber. This post is a different question on the same tutorial question. I did so because I was once advised not to ask two questions in the same post. But I must admit that I did post a modified duplicate (because I thought the closed one cannot be opened anymore). Sorry for that.